# Multithreading using WinAPI. Calculate PI

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I need to calculate PI using multiple threads for my homework. The problem is -- when using more than one thread, most of the time the sum is calculated incorrectly (smaller than it should be). I've spent quite some time on figuring it out, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious. Hoping for your help.

P.S. There was a question about the same task. However, my mistake is different.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>

#define THREAD_COUNT 2
#define N 10000000
#define BLOCK_SIZE 43087

typedef struct {
    unsigned startPos;
    int threadInd;
    double threadSum;
    bool isCalculating;
} ThreadArg;

HANDLE* threads;
HANDLE* events;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID);
void calculate(double* sum, unsigned start);

int main() {
    unsigned cursor = 0;
    ThreadArg* params = NULL;
    threads = NULL;

    if (THREAD_COUNT > 1) {
        params = (ThreadArg*)malloc(sizeof(ThreadArg)*(THREAD_COUNT - 1));
        threads = (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)*(THREAD_COUNT - 1));
        events = (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)*(THREAD_COUNT - 1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
        ThreadArg arg;
        arg.isCalculating = true;
        arg.startPos = cursor;
        arg.threadInd = i;
        arg.threadSum = 0;
        params[i] = arg;
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc, (LPVOID)(&params[i]), CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);
        events[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
        cursor += BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    unsigned startTime = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
        ResumeThread(threads[i]);
    }

    double mainSum = 0;
    while (cursor < N) {
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
            if (!params[i].isCalculating) {
                params[i].startPos = cursor;
                SetEvent(events[i]);
                cursor += BLOCK_SIZE;
            }
        }
        calculate(&mainSum, cursor);
        cursor += BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    bool allFinished;
    do {
        allFinished = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
            if (params[i].isCalculating) {
                allFinished = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(!allFinished);

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT - 1; ++i) {
        mainSum += params[i].threadSum;
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);
    }

    printf("Time: %d\n", clock() - startTime);
    printf("PI = %.7f\n", mainSum/N);
    free(threads);
    free(params);
    system("pause");
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lParam) {
    ThreadArg* param = (ThreadArg*)lParam;
    while (true) {
        ResetEvent(events[param->threadInd]);
        calculate(&param->threadSum, param->startPos);
        InterlockedDecrement((LONG*)&param->isCalculating);
        WaitForSingleObject(events[param->threadInd], INFINITE);
        InterlockedIncrement((LONG*)&param->isCalculating);
    }
}

void calculate(double* sum, unsigned start) {
    int endLoop = start + BLOCK_SIZE;
    double x;
    for (unsigned i = start; i < endLoop; ++i) {
        if (i < N) {
            x = (i + 0.5) / N;
            *sum += 4 / (1 + x*x);
        } else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running same code without threads? I.e. replace `ResumeThread` call with direct call of `ThreadProc` and check that everything works correctly.

Comment: It seems to work fine. Also works fine when all calculation happens in the main thread. It starts to malfunction somewhere towards the end of calculation because the result fluctuates around first or second digit after decimal point

Comment: Then it definitely looks like race condition, which is probably cause by lack of proper synchronization between threads. I can see that you use some variables/fields like `isCalculating` with _some_ synchronization and even atomic operations (which sounds too hard for that kind of problem). I'd suggest you assigning an event to each thread ("finished calculation") and then use `WaitForMultipleObjects` in the main thread instead for for loop.

Comment: @yeputons Don't know why I haven't used it earlier. It works now, thanks a lot

Comment: This is…not a sensible assignment. You are in an unenviable position. There is literally nothing to be gained by throwing multiple threads at this problem, and plenty to be lost in terms of synchronization bugs and the inevitable slow-downs involved in getting those bugs squashed. Calculating pi does not lend itself well to this type of parallelization. The overhead kills any possible performance gains, likely many times over.

Comment: @CodyGray - you mistake, really with parallelization this sum can calc in several time faster compare with single thread

Answer (score 0):

you not need events at all. working thread never must wait. all can be done with interlocked operations.

```
class CALC_TASK 
{
    C_ASSERT(sizeof(double)==sizeof(__int64));

    union {
        double _sum;
        __int64 _value;
    };

    double _step;
    LONG _startPos, _maxPos, _blockSize;

    static double calculate(LONG i, LONG count, double step) 
    {  
        double x, sum = 0.0;  

        do 
        {
            x = (i-- - 0.5) * step;  
            sum += 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);  
        } while (--count);

        return step * sum;  
    } 

    void add(double x)
    {
        union {
            double sum;
            __int64 value;
        };

        union {
            double new_sum;
            __int64 new_value;
        };

        sum = _sum;

        for ( ; ; value = new_value)
        {
            new_sum = sum + x;

            new_value = _InterlockedCompareExchange64(&_value, new_value, value);

            if (new_value == value)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    BOOL getBlock(LONG& pos, LONG& count)
    {
        LONG startPos, newPos, curPos;

        for (startPos = _startPos ; startPos < _maxPos; startPos = curPos)
        {
            if ((newPos = startPos + _blockSize) > _maxPos)
            {
                newPos = _maxPos;
            }

            curPos = _InterlockedCompareExchange(&_startPos, newPos, startPos);

            if (curPos == startPos)
            {
                pos = newPos, count = newPos - startPos;
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    void calculateEx()
    {
        LONG i, count;

        double step = _step;

        while (getBlock(i, count))
        {
            add(calculate(i, count, step));
        }
    }

public:

    double getsum()
    {
        return _sum;
    }

    CALC_TASK(LONG maxPos, LONG blockSize)
    {
        _startPos = 0, _blockSize = blockSize, _maxPos = maxPos, _sum = 0.0, _step = 1.0 / (double)maxPos;
    }

    static DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc(PVOID pct)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<CALC_TASK*>(pct)->calculateEx();
        return 0;
    }
};

double test(LONG maxPos, LONG blockSize)
{
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetNativeSystemInfo(&si);
    PHANDLE phThreads = 0;
    ULONG nThreads = 0;

    CALC_TASK ct(maxPos, blockSize);

    if (1 < si.dwNumberOfProcessors)
    {
        ULONG n = si.dwNumberOfProcessors - 1;

        phThreads = (HANDLE*)alloca(n * sizeof(HANDLE));

        do 
        {
            if (*phThreads = CreateThread(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, CALC_TASK::ThreadProc, &ct, 0, 0))
            {
                nThreads++, phThreads++;
            }
        } while (--n);
    }

    CALC_TASK::ThreadProc(&ct);

    if (nThreads)
    {
        WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreads, phThreads - nThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
        do 
        {
            CloseHandle(*--phThreads);
        } while (--nThreads);
    }

    return ct.getsum();
}

void testEx()
{
    ULONG dwStart = GetTickCount();

    double d = test(0x10000000, 0x8000);

    dwStart = GetTickCount() - dwStart;

    DbgPrint("pi = %.15f, %u milliseconds\n", d, dwStart);
}
```

in my test with 8 core/treads it take ~ 0.5 second for `0x10000000` steps. with single thread this take ~3.5 seconds.

as alternative you can use `openMP`

```
double calculateOMP(int num_steps) 
{  
    double x, sum = 0.0, step = 1.0 / (double) num_steps;  

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) private(x) 

    for (int i = num_steps; i > 0; --i)
    {
        x = (i - 0.5) * step;  
        sum += 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);  
    }

    return step * sum;  
}
```

for this you need use `/openmp` option and add `vcomp.lib` to linker input